# GL ES: Fragment shader optimization

Tags: performance, optimization, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

**Summary:**
I get FPS slowdown as soon as I try to tint the sprites (i.e: multiply texture with color in the fragment shader)

**Details:**

Hardware: iPod touch 4

Using 64x64 png texture containing alpha channel, rendering with glEnable(GL_BLEND). (A smiley face with a drop shadow)

I am drawing 700 sprites on the screen using glDrawArrays. And yes I am batching all of these in a single draw call. Following shows Vertex data structure:

```
struct Vertex {
    float Position[2];
    float Color[4];
    float Texture[2];
};
```

Yes I am sending colour with each vertex because I selectively need to tint some sprites but not others. Following is the fragment shader I am using:

```
varying lowp vec2 TexCoord;
uniform sampler2D TextureSampler;

void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D( TextureSampler, TexCoord );
}
```

Till now it is working GREAT, giving me full 60 FPS !!!

BUT

As soon as I change the fragment shader to the following (to allowing tinting):

```
varying lowp vec4 DestinationColor;
varying lowp vec2 TexCoord;
uniform sampler2D TextureSampler;

void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D( TextureSampler, TexCoord ) * DestinationColor;
}
```

The performance drops to 47 FPS only due to this single change {just by multiplication with **ONE** vector} (FPS measured using xcode instruments and OpenGL detective). Any ideas what is going on ?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I've also tried stripping off per vertex color attribute:

```
struct Vertex {
    float Position[2];
    float Texture[2];
};
```

And modifying the fragment shader as follows:

```
precision lowp float;
varying lowp vec2 TexCoord;
uniform sampler2D TextureSampler;

void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D( TextureSampler, TexCoord ) * vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

It is running at 52 FPS for 700 sprites (a gain of only 5 FPS). So this is not interpolation, seems like the multiplication is extremely expensive. Just this ONE multiplication?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience alpha blending tends to drop frame rate pretty quickly, especially on older devices. My guess is that multiplying that color actually involves a lot of extra calculation for the GPU (to factor in and multiply the color already in the framebuffer). Honestly if you're still at 47 fps on a 4th gen iPod touch it seems like you're doing pretty well. You'll probably be back up to 60 on a newer device. If you're batching the draw calls there's not really much more optimization to do with such a simple shader.

You could try rendering all the sprites where the destination color won't effect the final color first as a separate batch using your original texture lookup shader and then draw the rest using the shader that multiplies the color, but the overhead of the sorting might not be worth it.

**EDIT**

There is another SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5508874/2279993) that might be more what you're looking for. It basically says that higher precision floating point multiplication in the fragment shader can kill performance. You might be able to manually set the precision of your sampler to be lower and boost performance that way.

Comment: Well as I mentioned in the question, I am already getting 60 FPS on iPod 4 while rendering 700 sprites. **BUT** as soon as I apply tint in the fragment shader (i.e.: multiply color with the texture) the FPS suddenly drops to 47 FPS. Selective rendering seems to be a good idea, thanks :). But can you pin-point the reason for the slowdown? It is just multiplying 2 vectors!!

Comment: So what I tend to see on my iPhone 4 is that the more complicated I make my fragment shaders the faster my fps drops. Especially when I have texture lookups and/or alpha blending. Even really simple calculations can drop the fps really quickly on the older devices. To be honest I don't know enough about the inner workings of OpenGL to explain why that is but my guess is that extra multiplication just happens to be pushing your hardware just past it's max fps threshold.

Comment: I've edited the question above to add new information. Basically I am already using lowp :). I also tried to multiply by a constant color vector (please see above edit). Now I am getting 52 FPS. A drop of 8 FPS due to only ONE multiplication? Seems like vector multiplication is very expensive.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your fps if you disable blending but leave everything else the same?

Comment: With GL_BLEND **disabled** and no tinting, I am getting a rock solid 60 FPS when rendering 3100 sprites !!!

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would have expected. I can't tell you exactly why the extra vec4 multiplication has such a performance hit but it's definitely the blending that's the real source of the slow down. The blend + multiply is just tipping your ipod over the performance edge. Apple suggests using PVRTC textures to help speed things up and maybe that'll help speed up your multiply. I still think you're doing ok with that many sprites on an older device though.